# Rspec test for testing create controller of nested resource inside parent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My Rails API app has two resources: article (parent) and annotation (child). I want to test that, when a parent is created, any children if specified are also created. So I want to test this creation INSIDE the parent's create controller test, in additional to the child's create controller test itself.

I've gotten the JSON request to work fine but I'm not sure how to structure my RSpec test

```
{
  "article": {
    "original_language": "ja",
    "title": "日本のコンビニが中東で初めて店を開く",
    "body": "コンビニの会社「セブン－イレブン・ジャパン」は１３日、中東のＵＡＥ＝アラブ首長国連邦のドバイに新しい店を開きました。日本のコンビニが中東に店を開くのは初めてです。\nＵＡＥには２４時間開いている店がほとんどありませんでした。このため、ＵＡＥの中のアブダビ首長国の王族（＝王と王の親類）が新しいやり方の店を開いてほしいと頼んでいました。\n新しい店では、特に弁当やおにぎりなどを売りたいと考えています。ＵＡＥの人が好きなインドのスパイスを入れたり、大きなソーセージをのせたりしたおにぎりも作りました。新しい店の社長は「ＵＡＥにはいろいろな国の人たちが来ています。お客様がみんな喜ぶような店にしたいです」と話していました。\nセブン－イレブン・ジャパンは、これから３年でＵＡＥに１００の店を開く予定です。",
    "source_name": "NHK Easy News",
    "source_url": "http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010269131000/k10010269131000.html",
    "privacy_status": 1,
    "scheduled_date": null,
    "level": 3,
    "annotations": [
      {
        "destination_language": "en",
        "authority_level": 1,
        "source_text": "コンビニ",
        "location_start": 1,
        "location_end": 5,
        "category": 0,
        "definition": "Convenience Store",
        "reading": null,
        "translation": null,
        "usage_note": "Convenience stores are everywhere in Japan. Most open 24/7. The big chains are 7/11, Lawson, Family Mart, Sunkus, and Circle K.",
        "specific_note": null,
        "paragraph_id": 1
      },
      {
        "destination_language": "en",
        "authority_level": 1,
        "source_text": "コンビニ",
        "location_start": 1,
        "location_end": 5,
        "category": 0,
        "definition": "Convenience Store",
        "reading": null,
        "translation": null,
        "usage_note": "Convenience stores are everywhere in Japan. Most open 24/7. The big chains are 7/11, Lawson, Family Mart, Sunkus, and Circle K.",
        "specific_note": null      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt so far. I realize that what I'm doing is not nesting the annotations under article like in JSON. How can I do that?

```
@article_attributes = create_prospective(scope: :article)
@annotation_attributes_valid = create_prospective(scope: :annotation)
@annotation_attributes_invalid = create_prospective(scope: :annotation, trait: :invalid)
post :create, {user: @user.id, article: @article_attributes, annotations: @annotation_attributes_valid }, format: :json
```

Note: create_prospective is a helper method for FactoryGirl

Controller

```
def create
    @article = current_resource_owner.articles.build(article_params)

    if @article.save
      annotation_result = create_annotation(@article, params[:article][:annotations])

      render json: {article: @article, total_number_annotations: annotation_result[:total_count], number_annotations_succeeded: annotation_result[:success_count], number_annotations_failed: annotation_result[:failure_count], successful_annotations: annotation_result[:success_list], failed_annotations: annotation_result[:failure_list]}, status: annotation_result[:api_status]
      # end
    else
      render json: { errors: @article.errors }, status: 422
    end
```

end

Note: create_annotation is a concern that saves the annotations, to be reusable in both the article controller and annotation controller

Answer (score 0):

Your specs are creating actual `Article` and `Annotation` objects instead of attribute hashes, and as you said, you haven't nested the `Annotation` inside the `Article`. The first thing you should do is create a parameter hash that you can verify has the same structure as your working JSON request. I'd expect that to look like this:

```
article_data = attributes_for(:article, annotations: [attributes_for(:annotation)])
```

Then, you should be able to post your attribute data properly to your controller:

```
post :create, article: article_data, format: :json
```

Once you have the spec working, you can simplify your controller a bit by using [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) on your `Article` model. Rails provides that for just this case, and it helps you validate all of your objects at once in case you don't want the `Article` to be created with invalid `Annotation`s, and it plays nicely with the way Rails does [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)

Comment: Thanks. This works like a charm. My create_prospective helpers is basically the same attributes_for so that part wasn't the issue. But the nesting you mentioned was the missing part. Thanks!